# Как сформировать запрос в БД для подсчета рейтинга автора

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Имеются 3 таблицы

1. `author` - автор
2. `article` (связь с author один ко многим) - статья
3. `article_vote` (связь с `article` один ко многим, ка каждый лайк создаётся запись с `article_id`) - голосование за статью

Подскажите, как получить автора, а также суммарное количество голосов за статьи автора (рейтинг авторов формируется из кол-ва голосов за статьи автора)?

Comment: Схему таблиц предлагается угадать? А так через два join'а соединить и выбрать все нужные данные.

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае как-то так:

```
SELECT aut.Name, art.Name, COUNT(vot.ID)
FROM Author aut
JOIN Article art ON art.AutID = aut.ID
JOIN article_vote vot ON vot.ArtID = art.ID
WHERE art.ID = 1
GROUP BY aut.Name, art.Name
```

Пример схемы:

```
create table Author(
   ID integer NOT NULL,
   Name char (30) NOT NULL 
 );

 create table Article(
   ID integer NOT NULL,
   AutID integer NOT NULL,
   Name char (30) NOT NULL 
 );

 create table article_vote(
   ID integer NOT NULL,
   ArtID integer NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO Author VALUES (1, "Pert"), (2, "Vasua");

 INSERT INTO Article VALUES (1, 1, "Pert is amazing"), (2, 1, "Pert the Best"), (3, 2, "About"), 
                            (4, 2, "To be or not to be"), (5, 2, "SQL for Dummies");

 INSERT INTO article_vote VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 4);
```